# QGIS - Rendering of two overlapping attributes of one line feature

Tags: qgis

I have a network of routes and some polylines belong to 2 different routes at the same time (see picture). Is it possible to display these lines in a way that I do not need to setup a rule-based rendering for the exception of the depicted case? I would like to achieve that both lines lie next to each other like in subway system maps...[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @George has mentioned, one way would be to offset the line with `translate` in the field calculator.

[image]

If we have path A and path B, we can offset path in one direction by choosing to alter it's x or y coordinates by a factor.  The greater the factor the greater the offset.  Here I have tried a few different values -

[image]

To get this result:

[image]

The change is subtle but it seems like that's what you are looking for.  Alternatively, if you *only* want to offset the overlapping segment of the line, convert your line to nodes with `Geometry Tools > Extract Nodes` then choose the nodes associated with your overlapping segment, perform a translation, and then reconnect the points with the `Points2One` plugin.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out as this seems to be what I am looking for. Especially your last remarks are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use an offset in the style, though I think you would need to use a rule based style otherwise the line would be offset everywhere. Alternatively, you could use a data-driven variable for the offset and then test for the overlap in the expression, but this would probably get very slow, very quickly.